# Взаимосвязь массивов внутри переменных

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться. Почему при изменении значения i-го элемента массива 2, меняется и значение i-го элемента массива 1, по образцу которого был создан массив 2. Не могу въехать.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = array1;
array2[0] = 100;
alert(array2) // [100, 2, 3]
alert(array1) // [100, 2, 3] ????why????
```

Comment: array2.push(array1)

Comment: вы скопировали не массив, а ссылку на него.

Comment: Все объекты в JS передаются и присваиваются по ссылке. И да, массив -- это объект

Comment: Всем спасибо, попробую с этим разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что array2 является ссылкой на array1. Это по сути тот же самый массив, а не его копия.